# Move method to streambuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

```
List<Photo> imgList = [];
  Future getCarouselWidget() async {
    var firestore = Firestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn =
        await firestore.collection("history").getDocuments();
    List pics = qn.documents
        .map((it) => Photo(it['photo'].toString(), it['name'].toString(), it['address'].toString()))
        .toList();
    return imgList = pics;
  }
```

Hi all, when I make changes in my DB I dont see them in my app? can anybody help me or guid me how to wire this to stream builder or query the stream

```
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: Firestore.instance
                    .collection('swimfinderlakes')
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time Firestore has a change, it'll trigger the `StreamBuilder`. U can then access the most recently update with the `snapshot` on the `builder` method. Then you can use it to update the ui accordingly.

```
        StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: Firestore.instance
                .collection('swimfinderlakes')
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
             if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
               if (snapshot.hasData) {
                 List pics = qn.documents
                   .map((it) => Photo(it['photo'].toString(), 
                   it['name'].toString(), it['address'].toString())).toList();
                 return pics;
               }
             } else {
               return  CircularProgressIndicator();
             }
           }
```